# Disabling a Button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm new to Swift, but trying to figure out how to disable this button when it is pressed. I have the following:

```
@IBAction func IBbtnUpdateTap(sender: UIButton){

    if imageNumber == 0 {
        IBbtnUpdateTap.enabled = false
    }
```

I'm not sure why it's giving me problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IBbtnUpdateTap` isn't the button. The button is `sender`

```
 @IBAction func IBbtnUpdateTap(sender: UIButton){

    if imageNumber == 0 {
        sender.enabled = false
    }
```